# chart.js is not visible on blank data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to show the graph even with no data. In that case x-axis and y-axis show be visible.  Here is the code I've used. How can I get the graph visible even with no data.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <script>
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
        var barChart = new Chart(ctx,{
            type: 'line',
            data:{
                datasets: [
                    {
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "#22a7f0",
                        borderColor: "#22a7f0",
                        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                        borderDash: [],
                        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointBorderWidth: 1,
                        pointHoverRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                        pointRadius: 5,
                        pointHitRadius: 40,
                        data: []
                    }
                ]                                                                                                                                                           
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: true,
                    //mode: 'single',
                    mode: 'label'
                },
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display:false
                            }
                        }],
                    yAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display:false
                            }

                        }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to show the graph then, there's no need to set the `gridLines` option. It is shown by default.

Also, there's no `labels` in the `data` object hence, the grid-lines are not shown properly.

Here's the fixed version:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        datasets: [{
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "#22a7f0",
            borderColor: "#22a7f0",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 40,
            data: []
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'label'
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 500
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Off-topic: isn't chutzpah (brass, confidence, arrogance) something one has, rather than something one is? Maybe there's a joke I've missed...

Comment: @halfer lol.. I even forgot I have that avatar xD... btw, no idea about that joke tho :)

Comment: Ah righto. Well, it doesn't matter, but afaik the message doesn't make much sense `:-)`. Interesting [WP article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chutzpah).

Comment: Thanks. It works. can you tell me how to get customized units on Y-axis

Comment: @Alex you mean, to start y-axis from 0?

Comment: yes I need range from 0 to 500 with interval of 100

Comment: @Alex you could set the *min* and *max* value for `ticks`. check edited answer :)

Comment: Great. Thanks Men :)